# Progress View Linked with Background Download Alamofire.download Swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, alamofire, uiprogressview

i have an collection view. and inside cell contains image view, label, and progress view like this
[image]

i want to make if cell tapped, it starts download pdf file and the progress view start animating and if the pdf file already downloaded, it display the pdf file instead download again.

the download started but the progressview didn't animate until the download finished it still 0%. and Also get the message says `Invalid URL scheme for background downloads: (null). Valid schemes are http or https`
but the download succeded

here what i've don this far 
https://gist.github.com/asdwd5/31919950383f290709c5934853c3e9fc

and on my collection view cell
https://gist.github.com/asdwd5/c83cc2f2975c1beeb7de487696e99275

I know my code is not clear and disorganized. I'm very new to swift, and just follow any tutorial i found.

Answer (score 0):

After investigation of the code it is possible to conclude that:

When you press required item of the table view you should start animation of the `activityIndicator`.

```
cell.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
```

And there is no need to perform manual hide of the `activityIndicator` as you do in controller.

```
cell.activityIndicator.hidden = true
```

Just smile use this method.

```
cell.activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true;
```

Comment: i mean, the progress view start animating if download starter. my progress view in collection view cell named progressDownload